# how to use susy with compass.app

Tags: susy-compass

I'm using compass.app from compass.handlino.com and I'm wondering if it's possible to use the Susy responsive grid system without have to use the command line.

I chose Compass.app because it allows me to use SASS and SCSS and watch files without using the command line, so i'd like to know if its also possible to use Susy.

I've searched everywhere and I haven't been able to find a concise answer.  Can I use Susy with Compass.app for windows, and if so How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use compass.app or fire.app create a susy project:

Create Project > susy > project

Screenshot:
http://d.pr/i/t4XN

or add `@import "susy";` in your scss file directly.

Comment: Awesome! This was great, and thanks for the screenshot too! : ]